# State Restoration not working when presenting viewcontroller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller, state-restoration

I am not using storyboards. And currently in ViewController1. Here on a button click event I call this code.

```
InnerViewController *innerVc = [[InnerViewController alloc]  initWithNibName:@"InnerViewController" bundle:nil titleText:@"vaibhav"];
    UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:innerVc];
    nav.restorationIdentifier = @"innerNavSR";
    [self.navigationController presentViewController:nav animated:YES completion:nil];
```

And in InnerViewController `restorationIdentifier` and `restorationClass` is given. I have proper methods written for restoration.like

```
viewControllerWithRestorationIdentifierPath
encode and decode restoration.
```

If I change my

```
[self.navigationController presentViewController:nav animated:YES completion:nil];
```

to

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:innerVc animated:YES];
```

It works fine. What am I missing or doing wrong with present. For a try I have even tried this :

```
[self presentViewController:nav animated:YES completion:nil];
```

But no use. Doesn't work.

Result when presenting is -

`viewControllerWithRestorationIdentifierPath`

and `decodeRestorableStateWithCoder`are getting called. call is also coming in `viewdidload` but not in `viewwillappear`. and I am visually seeing `Viewcontroller1`. However it is all fine with `push`

Is something special required with **present**  ??

Answer (score 4):

I have had a very similar issue and struggled for half a day. The problem was I was assigning a restoration identifier when regularly creating the view controller, but was NOT assigning it, when creating the restored instance.

In your particular scenario, make sure, that when restoring the inner NC, it is also assigned @"innerNavSR" identifier before it is returned to the OS.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you very much, you just saved me a ton of hair pulling!